# What is causing this error - Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, task})

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Tried lots of different things, keep getting this error -

**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, task}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

I cant seem to get why this error is coming up, I dont see anywhere an object is being passed in where it shouldnt be. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function DisplayTasks() {

let taskList = [{id: "1234", task: "Bake a cake"}];

const [list, setList] = useState(taskList)
const [input, setInput] = useState("");

const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("ran")

    let newNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    let stringNum = newNum.toString()

    setList([...list, {id: stringNum, task: input}])

    console.log(list)

    setInput("")
}


const handleChange = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
}

const generateTasks = list.map((item) =>{

return      <>
                <div key={item.id}>
                    <h1>{item.task}</h1>
                </div>
            </>
    

}
)
return (
    <>
   {list}
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <label htmlFor="tasktitle"></label>
       <input name="tasktitle" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Add a Task" value={input}></input>
    <button type="submit">Click here to add task</button>
    </form>

    {generateTasks}
    </>
)
```

}

Comment: perhaps `item.name` is contributing since that is not set. You should have `item.task` I think

Comment: The problem is `{list}`.  That's an array, but not an array of JSX objects, it's an array of regular object and react does not know how to render it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know what you really want to do with your `list` state but what you *are* doing right now in your return statement is totally wrong.

You cannot simply just return `list` state like that.

What do you want with it? Return a `<p>`? `<input>`? Which element?

```js
return (
    <>
   {list} <------------------------- this is a problem
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <label htmlFor="tasktitle"></label>
       <input name="tasktitle" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Add a Task" value={input}></input>
    <button type="submit">Click here to add task</button>
    </form>

    {generateTasks}
    </>
)
```

And for the second thing. "name" is not an object in your `list` state so you cannot select an item from an array that does *not* exists.

You can choose between `id` or `task` - as specified in your state.

```js
const generateTasks = list.map((item) =>{

return      <>
                <div key={item.id}>
                    <h1>{item.name}</h1> <---------------- either use item.id or item.task
                </div>
            </>
    

}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first part answered it. The item.name was a mix-up, I accidentally changed it to that while trying to fix the original problem, that was wrong but that wasn't the main thing causing the issue.

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you defined `item.name`, I think you want `item.task`